# EMF image missing border in Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, emf

I have an EMF image with four borders (bottom, top, left, right). In Paint, I can see the borders properly. But when I insert this EMF file into a Word document, only bottom and right borders are visible, left and top border are not shown. [This is what it looks like in Paint and Word.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ovhd.png)  I am using Microsoft Word 2016. How can I make left and top borders to show properly in Word? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Word is cropping off the outside 1 px of the image. It's possible that Word it putting it's own border around the image and over the top of your border, effectively hiding it.  Try making your borders larger in the image or moving them farther from the edge of the image.

You can also just add a border to the image in Word and not worry about it.

Go to the Formatting tab, click Picture Border, and then select the color, thickness, and style of the border.

https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/word2016/formatting-pictures/1/